# vb.net controls set property

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

can you help me to solve my problem on vb.net
i want to change background color of one or more datagridview using check all component on form using controls..

```
For Each ctrl In ctrlParent.Controls
    If ctrl.GetType Is GetType(DataGridView) Then
        ....
    End If
Next
```

if i use ctrl.BackColor = Color.Black, that no make any change. but if i use ctrl.Backgroundcolor = Color.Black shows error : 'Backgroundcolor' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'
any idea?

can i access control preperty to change 'Backgroundcolor' property of datagridview? 
or any else?

note : ctrl.ForeColor = Color.Black -> successfully change font color on datagridview

Comment: Control does not have a BackgroundColor property ! It has a [BackColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yes i know... any idea to solve that?

Comment: use Control.BackColor... and NOT Back*ground*Color

Comment: nothing happen using Control.BackColor for datagridview as i tell before

Comment: Please read your question and edit it properly, using the correct words, backcolor or backgroundcolor...

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the type of controls directly to `DataGridView` in your loop.
Then set `BackgroundColor` accordingly:

```
For Each ctrl In ctrlParent.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)
    ctrl.BackgroundColor = Color.Black
Next
```